# (libGDX) unit test for key input: Using robot to simulate key press

Tags: java, libgdx

I want to use a bot to simulate the user pressing the left arrow key, then use this simulation for libGDX's "isKeyPressed" method below, but I keep getting the following error: Cannot invoke "com.badlogic.gdx.Input.isKeyPressed(int)" because "com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx.input" is null. How would I initialize it so that it is not null?

class GameScreenTest {

```
@Test
void movementLeft() throws AWTException {
    int x = 10;

    Robot robot = new Robot();
    int keyCodeLeft = KeyEvent.VK_LEFT;
    robot.keyPress(keyCodeLeft);
    robot.keyRelease(keyCodeLeft);

    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.LEFT)) {
        x -= 5;
    }

    assertEquals(5, x);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

`Gdx.input` is just a `public static` field on the `Gdx` class. You can initialize it to anything that implements the `Input` interface.

This means you can create your own class that implements `Input` and is aware of the `Robot` so that it can query the robot for the key-press status, for example:

```
public class RobotInput implements Input {

    private Robot robot;

    public RobotInput(Robot robot) {
        this.robot = robot;
    }

    /* loads of other methods from the Input interface omitted for brevity */

    @Override
    public boolean isKeyPressed(int key) {
        return robot.isKeyPressed(key);
    }
}
```

Then you can initialize `Gdx.input` like:

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
Gdx.input = new RobotInput(robot);

robot.keyPress(Input.Keys.LEFT);
if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.LEFT)) {
    x -= 5;
}

assertEquals(5, x);
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. In the RobotInput class, in the "isKeyPressed" method, it is saying I cannot resolve method "isKeyPressed" in "Robot"

Comment: That is because I don't know what framework you use, I don't know what your `Robot` looks like. But that's not important, what is important is that you can call whatever method on `Robot` that is appropriate to figure out if a key is pressed.

Comment: @s16, What @bornander is trying to say is that you can do what is needed in the RobotInput. When you press a button the method isKeyPressed will run with the appropriate key as the parameter. You can also do something inside that method like `if (key == Left) robot.movementLeft();` which should resolve.